# How do you show a context menu in a VS Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a custom editor (graphical editor) as a Visual Studio Code Extension, and want to show a context menu in a WebView when a given element is right clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this question about showing a menu in a Webview or in text editor?

Comment: In a WebView (i've updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can check VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) which includes [issue 54285](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54285) ("Contributed webview context menu action")

It is resolved by [PR 154524](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154524):

> ### Adds webview/context contribution

(Available today in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/))

> With these changes I was able to get modified version of GitLens to add custom menu items to a specific webview (e.g. the welcome view) with the following contribution:
>
> ```yaml
> "webview/context": [
>   {
>       "command": "gitlens.showSettingsPage",
>       "when": "webview == gitlens.welcome"
>   }
> ],
> ```
>
> Which looks like:
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/641685/178028928-c578511d-7edc-445f-b442-da3d3c4354eb.png]
>
> When executed, the command callback gets an arg which looks like `{ webview: 'gitlens.welcome; }` (where `gitlens.welcome` is the `viewType`/`providedWebviewId`  of that webview)
>
> With this contribution, extensions could then use their own context keys to hide and show the desired commands.

So, this PR adds:

> I've added a new `preventDefaultContextMenuItems` property on `WebviewPanelOptions` and on the `webviewOptions` object we pass to `registerWebviewViewProvider` which allows a webview to opt-out of the default cut/copy/paste (or any future) menu items.
>
> I've also provided 3 context keys for the context menu when clause:
>
> - `webview` — the extension provided id of the webview
>
>   - for webview panels and custom editors it is the `viewType`
>   - for webview views it is the view `id`
> - `webviewItem` — an optional value that an extension can provide in the DOM via a `data-vscode-context-menu-item` attribute, by searching for closest element to the element that triggered the context menu
> - `webviewItemElement` — an optional value that an extension can provide in the DOM via a `data-vscode-context-menu-item-element` attribute, by searching for closest element to the element that triggered the context menu (but only within the scope of the found item element
>
> Here's an example using the GitLens Rebase Editor:
>
> ```yaml
> "webview/context": [
>   {
>       "command": "gitlens.rebase.help",
>       "when": "webview == gitlens.rebase",
>       "group": "9_gitlens@1"
>   },
>   {
>       "command": "gitlens.rebase.copySha",
>       "when": "webview == gitlens.rebase && webviewItem == commit && webviewItemElement == sha",
>       "group": "1_gitlens@1"
>   },
>   {
>       "command": "gitlens.rebase.copyMessage",
>       "when": "webview == gitlens.rebase && webviewItem == commit && webviewItemElement == message",
>       "group": "1_gitlens@1"
>   },
>   {
>       "command": "gitlens.rebase.showCommitDetails",
>       "when": "webview == gitlens.rebase && webviewItem == commit",
>       "group": "2_gitlens@1"
>   }
> ],
> ```
>
> Here's the DOM -- I have:
>
> - `data-vscode-context-menu-item="commit"` on each of the commit rows, and
> - additional `data-vscode-context-menu-item-element` attrs on the message and
> - sha the with "`message`" and "sha" values respectively
>   [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/641685/179121227-2209c080-61cc-42bf-af3e-51110b476388.png]
>
> Here's the context menus in action:
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/641685/179120896-083265fe-3bff-4db2-9aa8-42ea81787bc1.png]
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/641685/179121048-abec0f5d-6818-4685-ae44-b833d7308707.png]
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/641685/179120915-5d279f98-6c2f-4f21-8112-6c8b90ba7713.png]
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/641685/179120947-8e9c8d7a-9434-4130-845c-36d0511636de.png]

Comment: I  used webviewItem and webviewItemElement and set data attribute on react treeview element the way it is explained, but I cannot see the context menu item after adding the when clause to webview/context. Am I missing something? How can we debug to check what data we are getting in when clause? @vonc please help

Comment: @hungryMind Good question, but I cannot test it right now. Could you ask a separate question? (with your setup, OS version, VSCode version)

Comment: @hungryMind There are many potential reasons for this. For instance, make sure that the `package.json` file of your extension has the context menu contributions correctly defined. The `when` clause should precisely match the conditions you want. Remember that the identifiers used in the `when` clause are case-sensitive and must match the `data-vscode-context-menu-item` attribute values you set in the WebView's HTML.